# Vista DPI Scaling: Cannot disable DPI Scaling for Wireshark

Tags: windows-7, wireshark, dpi, high-dpi

I'm trying to disable dpi scaling for Wireshark, except Windows won't let me:

[image]

Yet i pick any other random executable in the folder, `uninstall.exe` for instance, i can do it fine:

[image]

What gives?

---

i know Microsoft won't let you turn off scaling for their own signed applications:

[image]

But that's not the case here.

i also checked the `wireshark.exe` manifest, in the hopes of [finding a clue there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#declaring_dpi_awareness), only to discover that [Wireshark isn't designed to run on Windows](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:YWVAzRMM3tIJ:download.microsoft.com/download/8/e/4/8e4c929d-679a-4238-8c21-2dcc8ed1f35c/windows%2520vista%2520software%2520logo%2520spec%25201.1.doc%20windows%20logo%20requirements%20manifest&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgqiFL42LaawUK7TDOnUTqkyNICMRSadP6QmhIajf-DAcWhJVzHkWrZDRThMVaIaDIv_JDguUWq-weQbJtbfSPG8DqLhJ8pKwzzFvwz6iCZlWkoMFWno114kmGTaZGpuk-c-G55&sig=AHIEtbQwbibM30HYHCUP82Eh_87Z4JreDw&pli=1):

[image]

Why won't Windows let me disable high dpi scaling on `wireshark.exe`?

Comment: +1 for thinking of checking the manifest. :)  Have you tried running the "Compatibility Wizard" to see how it reacts? What edition of Vista is this?

Comment: i'm experiencing this on Windows 7, but presumably it applies to all versions of Windows that support dpi scaling, and the ability to turn it off (introduced with Windows Vista)

Comment: OK, what Edition of 7 is it then? Pro, Starter? 32-bit? 64-bit? It helps to formulate an answer when we have all applicable information. :)

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. It begs the question, does the edition of Windows (Starter, Home Basic, Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate, N, KN, VL) affect the ability to set compatibility flags?

Comment: Probably not in this case, but knowing it's 64-bit from the get-go would have helped. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the software you are using (Wireshark in this case) is 64-bit, then the compatibility boxes will be unavailable.

You can try setting the compatibility flags directly in the registry which are at the following registry location:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

In that key, create a (string) entry as such:

- Name: The full path to the application's .exe
- Type: REG_SZ (String)
- Data: HIGHDPIAWARE

Comment: Incredible. i had no idea that 64-bit apps couldn't be shimmed through the UI. Adding the registry key manually solved the issue. Great job!

Comment: I think it's because they figure there's no reason to make a 64-bit application "compatible" as they won't be "legacy" in the first place (currently, anyway :) ).

Comment: The most recent Windows 8 update did something to Powerpoint on my Surface Pro to make it all blurry. Disabling DPI scaling was the solution, but because it's 64-bit, I couldn't do it through the GUI. this solution worked like a charm, except that the data value for me needed to be "~ HIGHDPIAWARE" instead of "HIGHDPIAWARE"